# Access GCP project with company email "nongmail" and password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I am very new to GCP and need some help on how to access GCP project.

I have an assessment given by an employer to install an application in GCP. I am provided with a company "non Gmail"  emailID/password, and a link to the project. I have looked for resources online but do not know how to access this project. when I try to access via browser using this email, I get an error saying this is not Gmail id.   Can someone guide me how I can access a gcp project with non Gmail id? I appreciate your help.

Access your google project:

[ INSERT project link: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=single-project ]

Username: user@companyname

Password: *******

Update:

The user name had a typo and I was provided with correct user details later.

Comment: You cannot unless the email address is managed by Google Workspace or Identity Platform. If it is from one of those accounts, you would get a different error. Let the administrator know about your problem. Only they can help you.

Comment: I have updated my post. Can you tell me how I can access. I am sure there is a way to access. I am familiar with AWS but GCP is new for me. In aws there are some accounts which only have programmatic access. Can  this be similar IAM user?

Comment: Please reread my comment. You are not using a supported email address. Only Gmail, Workspace, or Identity Platform based emails work.

Comment: Hello @syed fayaz, if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it (✔️) as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their researches. Have a great day, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the GCP Projects with non-gmail Id unless it is associated with Google Workspace or [Cloud Identity account.](https://developers.google.com/identity/)

If the email doesn't work, the company probably didn't add the email account to the Google Project (IAM Roles), or the email is not registered with a Cloud Identity. You can only log into the GCP console using Google's credentials , and for that you need a google user account. If your account is a company email account, the admin has to create the user on their identity.

Refer to the link for [accessing a gcp account](https://serverfault.com/questions/937135/whats-the-correct-way-of-having-a-gcp-account-without-a-gsuit-account) .

**EDIT:**

As @syed fayaz said, also we need to check whether we have any typing error in credentials.